# Firestore where in multiple document IDs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting an array of document IDs from one collection that I'm trying to query another collection with. This is how my query looks:

```
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(this.props.userID)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const postIDs = snapshot.data().posts;

        firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("posts")
          .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", postIDs)
          .orderBy("timestamp")
          .get()
          .then((snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot.data());
          });
      });
```

It's saying `snapshot.data()` is undefined, so I assume something is wrong with the query. I can confirm that there are valid IDs in `postIDs`.

This is how the database is structured:

```
users:
-- user with userID
---- displayName
---- etc.
---- posts (array of postIDs)
posts:
-- post with postID
```

Comment: If snapshot.data() returns undefined, all that means is there were no documents that matched your query.  Without seeing the specific data you're working with, there's not much we can do to help, as we can't see for ourselves what your query would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `collection().get()`, the response does not hold `data()` or `id` properties because it returns multiple documents (theoretically, anyway), so you can only access those documents via the `docs` property, even if there is only one document matching the query.

So if you want to access the documents that match your query, do something like:

```js
firebase.firestore()
 .collection("posts")
 .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", postIDs)
 .orderBy("timestamp")
 .get()
 .then((snapshot) => {
    const posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    console.log(posts);
    ...
 }
```

You can only call `snapshot.data()` or `snapshot.exists` if you specified a single document in you query: `firestore().collection("posts").doc(someDocID).get()` like you did in your first query. If not then, refer to snapshot.docs

Comment: is there a limit on the number of elements in postIDs ?

Comment: I think length of 10 @KrishnaShetty